# How can I avoid a byte[] memory leak?

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak with byte[] and I would like to learn more about this to prevent it from happening in the future.

Here is my java code:

```
package server.world;

import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public class WalkingHandler {

    public static final int WIDTH = 12000;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 9900;

    private final TiledMap map;

    private WalkingHandler() {
        this.map = new TiledMap(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    private static class SingletonContainer {
        private static final WalkingHandler SINGLETON = new WalkingHandler();
    }

    public static WalkingHandler getSingleton() {
        return SingletonContainer.SINGLETON;
    }

    public boolean traversable(int x, int y, int direction) {
        int flag = map.getFlag(x, y);
        //System.out.println(direction);
        if (direction == 0 && (flag == 1 || flag == 4 || flag == 6 || flag == 7 || flag == 9 || flag == 11 || flag == 13 || flag == 14)) {
            return false;
        } else if (direction == 4 && (flag == 1 || flag == 7 || flag == 15 || flag == 10 || flag == 11 || flag == 12 || flag == 14 || flag == 5)) {
            return false;
        } else if (direction == 8 && (flag == 1 || flag == 2 || flag == 3 || flag == 4 || flag == 5 || flag == 6 || flag == 7 || flag == 12)) {
            return false;
        } else if (direction == 12 && (flag == 1 || flag == 3 || flag == 6 || flag == 9 || flag == 10 || flag == 11 || flag == 12 || flag == 8)) {
            return false;
        } else if(flag > 0 && flag < 15) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void initialize() throws Exception {
        long delta = System.currentTimeMillis();
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("data/lolmap.bin", "r");
        FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();
        MappedByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());
        int length = buffer.getInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            int x = buffer.getShort();
            int y = buffer.getShort();
            byte flag = buffer.get();
            map.flag(x, y, flag);
        }
        System.out.println("Loaded clipmap in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - delta) + "ms.");
    }

    private static class TiledMap {

        private final byte[] plane;

        public TiledMap(int width, int height) {
            this.plane = new byte[width * 10000 + height];
        }

        public int getFlag(int x, int y) {
            return plane[x * 10000 + y];
        }

        public void flag(int x, int y, byte flag) {
            this.plane[x * 10000 + y] = flag;
        }

    }

}
```

Would someone mind pointing out what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Please paste your code here instead of linking to it on pastebin.

Comment: @Aleksandr: how many times do you instantiate your TiledMap?  Besides that the "x*10000 + y" is counter-intuitive.  Most game designers do "y*1000 + x" to store/locate "things" in a 1-dimensional array containing 2D things.  Also, your messy *if direction / flags* thinggy can definitely be rewritten in a better way.

Comment: What memory leak are you looking for? You allocate memory and you use it. As long as you don't need the memory for anything else, it will not be garbage collected, even if it was not referenced, which all memory is in your case, as far as I see. So please explain, where you see which problem, if you are asking for help.

Answer (score 2):

you are creating a array with size 12000*10000+9900 that is 120_009_900 bytes (this is even wrongly initialized: you should allocate 12000*9900 spaces and get them with x*height+y)

```
private static class TiledMap {

    private final byte[] plane;
    private final int width,height;

    public TiledMap(int width, int height) {
        this.plane = new byte[width * height];
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getFlag(int x, int y) {
        return plane[x * height + y];
    }

    public void flag(int x, int y, byte flag) {
        this.plane[x * height + y] = flag;
    }

}
```

however you are better off getting how much space you need first from the file and then allocating

Comment: I have noticed that it's actually not a memory leak but it uses byte[] pretty bad. Check out this snapshot of the server. http://i55.tinypic.com/2vv9z5s.png

Comment: @akek yep that's all that one array

Comment: Any suggestions on how to decrease it? lol

I'm probably going to use a new method to read the maps lol.

Comment: @alek as I said first discover the needed size then allocate